# can chrome extension emmbed local swf , to load files?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, flash

i have swf mp3 player that i like to load mp3 files from local directory to the chrome extension.
my questions is :
1.can chrome extension embed swf file that comes with the extension.
2.can chrome extension load files from local drives . like FF extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Check out the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). Note that users will need to manually select the files or folders themselves. If you want full filesystem access, you need to create a native plugin and compile it for all the platforms you want to support (e.g. .dll for Windows, .so for Linux).

Answer (score 0):

For #2, sadly not possible. The Chrome extension model disallows direct access to local files for security reasons.

For #1, it's definitely possible. Worst case is that you'll have to write your own NPAPI plug-in that hosts Flash. I haven't yet found another extension that manages to simply embed Flash player. At least not without requiring individual end users to enable chrome-extension://*/ URLs in the Flash player security dialog. That might get you started.

Comment: someone pointed me to this source file that open local files :  http://code.google.com/p/pgn4web/source/browse/trunk/chrome-extension/chess-games-viewer.html

Comment: This is wrong. There's the File API for files that users input into input[type=file] and Chrome extensions can include native plugins with full access to anything on the computer. Also, as for flash, Chrome has flash built-in so that's not a problem.