# Cannot serve .swf files in a Chrome extension

Tags: flash, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

My Chrome extension serves a static .swf flash file and I'm sure it's in `web_accessible_resources` in `manifest.json`. However, if I try to load that file outside the extension, it will fail.

Here is a short example:

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "play1.swf"
  ]
}
```

`http://127.0.0.1:6663/test2.html`:

```
<style>
iframe, object {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}
</style>

<iframe src="chrome-extension://<extension_id>/play1.swf"></iframe>
<object data="chrome-extension://<extension_id>/play1.swf"></object>
```

[image: screenshot]

You can see that `play1.swf` is accessible in `<iframe>`s but not accessible in `<object>`s.

And it's weird that the webpage is working within `file://` protocol.

[image: screenshot_file]

Is it a bug, or it is how Chrome extensions work?

What can I do to make `play1.swf` runnable outside my extension?

My Chrome version is `54.0.2816.0 dev-m (64-bit)`.

Comment: What's the error message when you click the red entry in the network log?

Comment: @wOxxOm i can't see any error messages. http://pho.to/AFUoW

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791131/can-chrome-extension-emmbed-local-swf-to-load-files) if it can help you.